# Juice UI: Slider slide property

Tags: jquery, juice-ui

on jQuery layer the "slider"-control has got a property called "slide". So you are able to define a callback function, that is called when the slider changes its value. For example you are able to modify the value in an input control.
My question: Is there a slide property on juice layer? Or can anyone tell me, how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many slider plugins for jQuery - Juice UI uses the slider widget within jQuery UI. There is a large distinction there.

The "slide" you mention is actually an event, not a property. http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Are you asking what the server-side event is named? If so, it's named "Slide"

Or are you asking how to use javascript to add the same event handler for slide as you would without using Juice UI? If so, you'd target the control in the same manner.

```
<juice:slider ID="_Default" runat="server" ControlIDMode="Static"/>


$("_Default").slider({ slide: .... });
```

If you're trying to use both server-side and client-side events (like the example above) then you have to wire up the js portion differently using the amplify component, otherwise the server-side event won't trigger properly.

```
amplify.subscribe("_Default.slider.slide", function( ... ){ /* callback */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!
But for me there is no event on server-side called 'slide'. Strange ...
But I'll try out the examples, of which you have told